# Print class names to dictionary based on condition - BS4

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from a website, store it in a dictionary and print the result in a structured format to a csv table. 
So far my code looks like this and works almost the way I want to:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

URL = "https://database.globalreporting.org/reports/49283/"
r = requests.get(URL, verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
# print(soup.prettify())
table = soup.findAll('li', attrs={'class': 'list-group-item'})
print(table)

quotes = []

for row in table:
    quote = {}
    quote['Label'] = " ".join(row.getText().split())
    quotes.append(quote)
    for line in row.select('span[class]'):
        if line['class'][0] == 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success':
            quote['Tickmark'] = "Yes"
            quotes.append(quote)
        if line['class'][0] == 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-light':
            quote['Cross'] = "No"
            quotes.append(quote)

for quote in quotes:
    print(quote)

filename = 'CSR_Info.csv'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, ['Label','Tickmark','Cross'])
    w.writeheader()
    for quote in quotes:
        w.writerow(quote)
```

The problem is, that I always get no values at all for my two if-statements...

Output looks like this (commas without any value even though I expect a Yes/No):

```
Integrated:,,
```

The HTML part I scrape looks like this:

[image]

So what I need is not the text of the class but the class name itself to check for my if-statements.

Anyone an idea how to achieve this?

In the end my result should look like:

```
Integrated:,Yes,
```

or in case of a no:

```
Integrated:,,No
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print the `line['class']` you will see class_names return as list so class_names[0] should be `glyphicon` **NOT** `glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-light` that is why you are not getting value.

In order to resolve that I have added if condition to check length of the list if 3 then verify the following class name with and conditions.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

URL = "https://database.globalreporting.org/reports/49283/"
r = requests.get(URL, verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
# print(soup.prettify())
table = soup.findAll('li', attrs={'class': 'list-group-item'})
#print(table)

quotes = []

for row in table:
    quote = {}
    quote['Label'] = " ".join(row.getText().split())
    quotes.append(quote)
    for line in row.select('span[class]'):

       if len(line['class'])==3:
          if line['class'][0] == 'glyphicon' and line['class'][1] =='glyphicon-ok' and line['class'][2] =='text-success':
             quote['Tickmark'] = "Yes"
             quotes.append(quote)
          if line['class'][0] == 'glyphicon' and line['class'][1] =='glyphicon-remove' and line['class'][2] =='text-light':
             quote['Cross'] = "No"
             quotes.append(quote)

for quote in quotes:
    print(quote)

filename = 'CSR_Info.csv'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, ['Label','Tickmark','Cross'])
    w.writeheader()
    for quote in quotes:
        w.writerow(quote)
```

**Output**:

```
{'Label': 'Publication year: 2017'}
{'Label': 'Report type: GRI - G4'}
{'Label': 'Adherence Level: In accordance - Comprehensive'}
{'Label': 'Sector supplement: Not Applicable'}
{'Label': 'Integrated:', 'Cross': 'No'}
{'Label': 'Integrated:', 'Cross': 'No'}
{'Label': 'GRI Service: Materiality Disclosures Service'}
{'Label': 'Reporting period: ? - ?'}
{'Label': 'Reporting cycle: ?'}
{'Label': 'Language: ?'}
{'Label': 'Number of pages: ?'}
{'Label': 'SDGs:', 'Tickmark': 'Yes'}
{'Label': 'SDGs:', 'Tickmark': 'Yes'}
{'Label': 'CDP:', 'Cross': 'No'}
{'Label': 'CDP:', 'Cross': 'No'}
{'Label': 'IFC:', 'Cross': 'No'}
{'Label': 'IFC:', 'Cross': 'No'}
{'Label': 'OECD Guidelines:', 'Tickmark': 'Yes'}
{'Label': 'OECD Guidelines:', 'Tickmark': 'Yes'}
{'Label': 'UNGC:', 'Tickmark': 'Yes'}
{'Label': 'UNGC:', 'Tickmark': 'Yes'}
{'Label': 'ISO 26000:', 'Cross': 'No'}
{'Label': 'ISO 26000:', 'Cross': 'No'}
{'Label': 'AA1000:', 'Cross': 'No'}
{'Label': 'AA1000:', 'Cross': 'No'}
{'Label': 'Stakeholder Panel/Expert Opinion:', 'Cross': 'No'}
{'Label': 'Stakeholder Panel/Expert Opinion:', 'Cross': 'No'}
{'Label': 'External assurance:', 'Tickmark': 'Yes'}
{'Label': 'External assurance:', 'Tickmark': 'Yes'}
{'Label': 'Type of Assurance Provider: Accountant'}
{'Label': 'Assurance Provider: Pricewaterhouse Coopers'}
{'Label': 'Assurance Scope: Entire sustainability report'}
{'Label': 'Level of Assurance: Limited/moderate'}
{'Label': 'Assurance Standard AA1000AS:', 'Cross': 'No'}
{'Label': 'Assurance Standard AA1000AS:', 'Cross': 'No'}
{'Label': 'Assurance Standard ISAE3000:', 'Tickmark': 'Yes'}
{'Label': 'Assurance Standard ISAE3000:', 'Tickmark': 'Yes'}
{'Label': 'Assurance Standard: national (general):', 'Cross': 'No'}
{'Label': 'Assurance Standard: national (general):', 'Cross': 'No'}
{'Label': 'Assurance Standard: national (sustainability):', 'Cross': 'No'}
{'Label': 'Assurance Standard: national (sustainability):', 'Cross': 'No'}
```